# Asp.net Core 2.0.0 runtime error with Visual Studio 2017

Tags: .net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

Yesterday I updated Visual Studio to Version 15.3.1 and installed the .NET Core 2.0 SDK.
All my ASP.NET core projects (targeting net461) are now having this runtime error:

> System.IO.FileLoadException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.IO.FileSystem

Steps to reproduce:

1. New Project > ASP.NET Core Web Application > Web Application (Model-View-Controller) > OK
2. Edit the csproj changing the Target Framework to net461

> `<TargetFramework>net461</TargetFramework>`

Is anyone aware of a workaround?

Comment: Can you take a look at the solution for this item and see if it applies to your issue? 
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/95070/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-systemruntime-vers.html

Answer (score 0):

A complete uninstall and reinstall fixed this.